# Replace substring in a encrypted field in msql

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have an encrypted column in mysql . I need to replace a substring in it .

If it was not encrypted then I would have used

```
 UPDATE my_table 
 SET    my_field = REPLACE(my_field, 'olddata', 'newdata')
```

If it was entire column updation , I would use

```
  UPDATE my_table 
  SET    my_field = AES_ENCRYPT('newdata' , 'KEY') 
  where  AES_DECRYPT(my_field , 'KEY') = 'olddata'
```

But how do I use both the above codes together ?  REPLACE with AES_ENCRYPT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to:

1. decrypt
2. replace
3. encrypt again

```sql
UPDATE my_table 
   SET my_field = AES_ENCRYPT(REPLACE(AES_DECRYPT(my_field , 'KEY'), 'olddata', 'new data'), 'KEY') 
 WHERE AES_DECRYPT(my_field , 'KEY') LIKE '%olddata%'
```

Here is [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=796a739e1a30706bf816b1af8d2e8de5) demo